# Does Google Chrome Extensions support multithreaded programming?

Tags: multithreading, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Say, I want to open up a new thread each time a button is clicked in my extension, how can I do that?

I know that the various tabs are handled by a chrome task manager which treats each tab as a parallel process. Therefore, if the answer to my question is no, can we somehow exploit this task manager to have the same effect? Perhaps using some hidden tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with Web Workers: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: This isn't real threads though... was hoping for more power considering it's a Chrome app/extension.

Comment: Trying to find a way to do this with manifest v3, anyone had luck with this?