# Multithreading in a compute intensive (wasm) chrome extension

Tags: multithreading, google-chrome-extension, webassembly

I have a google chrome extension (manifest V3) that upon clicking, updates the badge text to indicate that it's working, then calls cpu intensive wasm, and finally removes the badge text on success. This works fine, except when the compute intensive wasm is being called because of another tab. Then the extension doesn't update the badge text immediately when clicked. This is happening because the wasm is blocking the single thread of the extension service worker, preventing it from responding to events until the compute is over. I'd love to throw the wasm computation into its own thread so that the UI responds without delay, however it doesn't seem like it's possible to get another thread in a chrome extension.

Some things I've thought of:

- There's [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395859/does-google-chrome-extensions-support-multithreaded-programming) that suggests using WebWorkers. From what I can tell that only applies to manifest V2 and background scripts, unless there's a secret permissions flag for webworkers in V3 that I'm not aware of
- I could inject a content into the page and use its thread, or have it spawn a webworker and proxy everything. This is brittle, complicated, and requires otherwise unnecessary permissions, as well as relying in tab existence to finish the computation.
- Switch to manifest V2. While potentially a valid solution, this is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Lizozom chrome now supports the offscreen api (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) which can then spawn web workers. It's a bit obtuse, but it does work